# Excel/vba find character, replace and make two characters after superscipt

Tags: vba, excel

What I want is to find "#" char, remove it and make 2 characters after it superscript.
I`ve got this code:

```
    pos = InStr(mycell.Value, "#")
    If pos > 0 Then
        mycell.Replace What:="#", Replacement:=""
        mycell.Characters(Start:=pos + 1, Length:=2).Font.Superscript = True
    End If
```

When I only replace - works. When I only make some chars superscript - works. When both - only replace.

Comment: What version of Excel?  Also, have you tried `mycell.Characters(Start:=pos, Length:=2).Font.Superscript = True` (`pos` instead of `pos`+1) instead?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables is right - after you replace `#` with "", the characters you want to superscript are at `pos` and `pos+1`. If they are the last two characters in the string, you are likely to have a "silent error", and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

pos + 1 needs to be pos because you've removed a character with your Replace method.  Tested and seems to work fine in Excel 2010.

```
pos = InStr(myCell.Value, "#")
If pos > 0 Then
    myCell.Replace What:="#", Replacement:=""
    myCell.Characters(Start:=pos, Length:=2).Font.Superscript = True
End If
```

Comment: Eh, Excel 2010 and still not working. Could you send me your file? I would like to test it